# remember SlickGrid scroll position

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I am using the SlickGrid for some project. I am finding some difficulties in achieving few functionality. Below are the features i want to implement but don't know how to achieve it using slickgrid.

***ScrollPosition reset issue :***

***Problem :***

I have a grid say 70x100. And my view port can accommodate max 7 Rows and 10 columns at a time.

Now user scrolls in grid and jumps to some specific cell say 15th Row and 17th Column. I am trying to use setScrollIntoView for (15,17) but problem is when slick grid gets render it resets all positions of cells and now cell(15,17) is not in view port. Now when i render grid, i am calling setScroolIntoView for (15,17) but slick grid doesn't have that cell value in viewport instead there is some other cell renderd on the same position and slick grid sets focus in that new cell instead of actual (15,17).

Can anyone plz suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Slickgrid's [gotoCell(row, cell)](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.grid.js#L3139) method:

Note that the function calls scrollCellIntoView, which should achieve what you want.

```
grid.gotoCell(15, 17)
```

Albert